# Drawing on mouse move with Canvas, HMTL5?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

What I am trying to achieve is a simple functionality to draw lines on a canvas when the mouse is clicked.

I have looked at code online and am trying to implement it myself but it won't work.

So far:

```
<html>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="500"> </canvas>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
var el = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var ctx = el.getContext('2d');
    var isDrawing;

    el.onmousedown = function(e) {

      isDrawing = true;
      ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    };

    el.onmousemove = function(e) {
      if (isDrawing) {
        ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
        ctx.stroke();
      }
    };
    el.onmouseup = function() {

      isDrawing = false;
    };

</script>
```

This doesn't output anything on the canvas however. I don't fully understand the event handling aspect of the code (i.e, e.clientX, e.clientY)
I suspect I must add to this code for these parts to have the desired effect?

Comment: It works for me, your canvas element is not closed btw. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7huq7/)

Comment: I missed that while pasting, it's there in my code though

Comment: Wow, that's strange that it works in jsFiddle, the exact same code doesn't work in my actual page.

Comment: In case this is your full code you are a. missing a doctype and b. missing a `body` enclosing your content. It won't make too much sense starting to debug things that are plain invalid.

Comment: @m90, this isn't the actual code for my page, just the relevant parts.

Answer (score 0):

Well at a cursory glance you are missing a ">" at the end of line #2.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues:

- Adjust your mouse positions by the offset of the canvas (unless your canvas is at top-left of the browser)
- do all drawing commands in mousemove (otherwise you will restroke the line with every ctx.stroke)

Here's example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/kkLrT/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var offsetX=BB.left;
    var offsetY=BB.top;

    var lastX,lastY;
    var isDown=false;

    canvas.onmousedown=handleMousedown;
    canvas.onmousemove=handleMousemove;
    canvas.onmouseup=handleMouseup;


    function handleMousedown(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         e.stopPropagation();
         lastX=e.clientX-offsetX;
         lastY=e.clientY-offsetY;
         isDown=true;
    }

    function handleMouseup(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         e.stopPropagation();
         isDown=false;
    }

    function handleMousemove(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         e.stopPropagation();

         if(!isDown){return;}

         var mouseX=e.clientX-offsetX;
         var mouseY=e.clientY-offsetY;

         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.moveTo(lastX,lastY);
         ctx.lineTo(mouseX,mouseY);
         ctx.stroke();

         lastX=mouseX;
         lastY=mouseY;
    }


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Drag mouse to draw.</h4>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So just use window.onload instead of $(function(){}).  None of my answer requires jQuery ;=)